# WPF Dictionary Binding by key does not work

Tags: binding, windows-8, dictionary, resources, key

I really don't get it.

I created a viewmodel-class, which contains two objects, like this one:

```
public class MyViewModel{

public MyFirstObject FirstObject {get;set;}
public MySecondObject SecondObject {get;set;}

...
// Constructors and so on...
}
```

The FirstObject looks like this:

```
public class MyFirstObject {

    public int Id {get;set;}
    ...
    // Constructors and so on...
    }
```

}

And MySecondObject contains a Dictionary:

```
    public class MySecondObject{

            public Dictionary<int, string> MyDict {get;set;}
            ...
            // Constructors and so on...
            }
}
```

What I want to do now, is to get the dictionarys value for a key, which is a refence to MyFirstObject.Id - like this:

```
mySecondObject.myDict[myFirstObject.Id]
```

Doing this in C# is easy, but now I want to do this in xaml.
I created a UserControl and set the DataContext to a MyViewModel-reference.

After that, I tried this:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding SecondObject[FirstObject.Id]} ../>
```

Unfortunately this is not working, because the key 'FirstObject.Id' can not be found.

Has anyone an idea how to fix that?

Thanks a lot!
CodeCannibal

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this in XAML. Just create a new property on your viewmodel which encapsulates this logic.

You can also delegate the `PropertyChangedEvent` to propagate your value changes:

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private MyFirstObject firstObject;
    public MyFirstObject FirstObject
    {
        get { return firstObject; }
        set { firstObject = value; PropertyChanged("MyDictValue"); }
    }

    private MySecondObject secondObject;
    public MySecondObject SecondObject
    {
        get { return secondObject; }
        set
        {
            secondObject = value; PropertyChanged("MyDictValue");
            // you can subscribe here also for your MyDict changes if it is an
            // observable and you can call PropertyChanged("MyDictValue"); 
            // in the change event etc
        }
    }

    public string MyDictValue 
    { 
        get { return SecondObject.MyDict[FirstObject.Id]; } 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

And bind to your new property:

```xml
<TextBox Text={Binding MyDictValue} ../>
```

With this approach you will have a place inside the `MyDictValue` to add additional logic like handling if `FirstObject` or `SecondObject` is null etc.

Comment: Well - I tried that, but this works only if the value will never update :)
I implemented an ObservableCollection-object, to make sure, that the value is always up-to-date. Binding to 'MyDictValue' won't do that.
And here is another important notice which I forgot to comment: I am developing a win8 app - not a wpf app. I tried to use multibinding in combination with a converter - but multibinding is not longer supporter in win 8 apps.

Comment: Yes the value won't update but you haven't mentioned in your question that you want updates. But nothing prevents you to delegate the events. You can fire the `PropertyChanged("MyDictValue")` in your FirstObject  and SecondObject setters. If your SecondObject is/has an `ObservableCollection` you can subscribe its events and you can fire the `PropertyChanged("MyDictValue")` etc.

Comment: Oh - know I see. Thank you - that is the solution I was looking for. If I got it working, I'll post my solution here.